# Disable Android SwipeRefreshLayout at specific area

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a Webview inside a SwipeRefreshLayout which works fine. But as soon as I need to scroll UP inside the webview, the pull to refresh function ist called. Is there a way to disable the function when a specific area inside the webview is touched? Here is my LayoutFile

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android:android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </android:android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a touch listener for the webview. In there, if the touch event coordinates are within your target area, you would call requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent on your parent (the SwipeRefreshLayout). You need to re-enable touch events on the parent on event Up or Cancel.

Something like this skeleton code below (parent is your SwipeRefreshLayout view):

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (touch in target area) {
            parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (disallowed parent) {
            parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
```

you can also try calling setEnabled(false) on the SwipeRefreshLayout view instead of requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent.

Another option you can consider is to enable the pull to refresh only if the scroll Y for the webview is 0, so if you're at the top of the webview content. When you start scrolling down, you would disable your parent (SwipeRefreshLayout) and, when you scroll back up and reach the top (scroll Y == 0), you would re-enable your parent.